# Speed up symfony performance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony project and some things are pretty slow. I have a huge database so the first thing I did was to use the server-side pagination. It works pretty great but I try to improve it again.

So I did some research and find ByteCode Cache could be a good solution. The  problem is the one who is recommended is APC and it doesn't seems to be updated anymore and last release is from 2012.

I continued my research and find Zend opcache. But again I can see some place where it's told it works to php7.0 but I can't find any documentation above php5.*

So my question is does ByteCode Cach is still a good solution.

And if someone can give me some advice to speed up my Doctrine request, even a word to help me knowing where and/or what to search.

Comment: If you're trying to improve performance by caching the results check this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html. There are plenty of alternatives to APC. If you want to cache queries and metadata, you can check this article for explanation https://coderwall.com/p/ry1y0a/improve-doctrine-performance-up-to-100-on-your-symfony2-project. Going further, if you really want to use APC, you should look for APCu, but nowadays I much more prefer Redis.

Comment: @user1970395 Ok i'll check that thanks !

Comment: Try [blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/features) – it show you bottlenecks of your application and gives advices how to resolve them (try 15 days trial).